# Why is "if x is none" statement not executing properly?

Tags: python

It's obvious I'm doing something wrong, but I can't find help online as to why. I want to create an if function that prints out that the inputted file contains no data. When I run this and request an empty.txt file, it skips straight to the else: and I get

Enter name of file: empty.txt

In the terminal, instead of the printed result, I'm asking for.

```
 # Ask user to input file, open and and read file

userinput = input('Enter name of file: ')

userfile = open(userinput)

data = userfile.read()

#if file is empty print "x contains no data"

if data is None:
    print(userinput + ' contains no data.')
else:
    print(data)

userfile.close()
```

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: `.read()` returns a string.  If the file was empty, you'd just get an empty string - rather than `None`.

Comment: @MarkRansom the terminal returns:  Enter name of file: empty.txt and a second empty line, and I'm guessing that is representative of the empty contents of my sample empty.txt file that I input.

Comment: `.read()` will never return `None`

Answer (score 0):

```
 # Ask user to input file, open and and read file

userinput = input('Enter name of file: ')

userfile = open(userinput)

data = userfile.read()

#if file is empty print "x contains no data"
if len(data) == 0:
    print(userinput + ' contains no data.')
else:
    print(data)

userfile.close()
```

this works, because read an empty file returns an empty string "", you can check it by condition len(data) == 0

Comment: Actually you can just use `if not data:` because an empty string is considered False, unlike any other string.